# VBA Send Email From Non-Default Account

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am logged in with two Outlook Accounts, and I need to send an e-mail with the one that is not set to default.

I tried using `.SendOnBehaulfOfName`, but even though it showed me the right account prior to sending the email, after I sent it I saw that it was sent from the default email (which is the wrong one).
I also tried using `.SendUsingAccount` but it did not change the "From" email.

```vb
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMail As Object
    Dim ol As Outlook.Application
    Set ol = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutlookMail
        .To = lista_envio
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = assunto_email
        .Display '
        .HTMLBody = mensagem
        .Attachments.Add (caminho)
        .SendUsingAccount = ol.Session.Accounts("Contato")
    End With

    Set OutlookMail = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    Set ol = Nothing
```

Using the `For each Account in Outlook.Application.Session.Accounts` method also doesn't work.

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that such an account configured in Outlook. If you want to see changes on the Outlook UI you need to call the `Display` methods after setting all properties via the Outlook object model.

If the other account is configured in Outlook (not just an additional store) you need to choose the [MailItem.SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) property which sets an `Account` object that represents the account under which the `MailItem` is to be sent. You could find the following sample code which demonstartes how to use it:

```
Sub SendUsingAccount() 
 Dim oAccount As Outlook.account 
 For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts 
   If oAccount.AccountType = olPop3 Then 
     Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem 
     Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
     oMail.Subject = "Sent using POP3 Account" 
     oMail.Recipients.Add ("someone@example.com") 
     oMail.Recipients.ResolveAll 
     Set oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount 
     oMail.Send 
   End If 
 Next 
End Sub
```

The `SendOnBehaulfOfName` property doesn't require an account configured in Outlook. Only permissions are required for sending on behalf of another person in Exchange.

Comment: Thank you very much.

My two problems were not using .Display in the last line and not using Set with .SendUsingAccount.